# UITextField not editing properly

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitextfield

I have 3 `UITextField`s which was given dynamically as below:

```
if(a isEqualtoString:@"1")
{

UITextField *t=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,20,20)];
t.text=s;
t.delegale=self;
[scroll addSubview:t];

}
if(a isEqualtoString:@"2")
{
UITextField *t=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,20,20)];
t.text=p;
t.delegale=self;
[scroll addSubview:t];


}
if(a isEqualtoString:@"3")
{
UITextField *t=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,20,20)];
t.text=r;
t.delegale=self;
[scroll addSubview:t];

}
```

My problem is in `didBeginEditing` of these textfields i had written `errT.hidden=YES;`

this is my code but i am unable to edit those textfields and i have given delegate in .h

also. What to do? I have tried many solutions that didn't helped me. Help me

UPDATE:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if(textField==t)
    {
    err.hidden=YES;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please Clarify Are you not able to edit the textfield value or didbegin editing method is not call

Comment: code for didbeginediting

Comment: - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
are you talking about this method

Comment: see my update in question that is my didbegin editing

Comment: First of all please show ur code properly.. what is that p, s, r ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
if(a isEqualtoString:@"1")
{
    ....
    t.text = @"s";
    ....
}
if(a isEqualtoString:@"2")
{
    ....
    t.text = @"p";
    ....
}
if(a isEqualtoString:@"3")
{
    ....
    t.text = @"r";
    ....
}
```

Hope, it'll help you.

Comment: that is fine and in mycoe i have given it properly .

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand if your question is that `textFieldDidBeginEditing` is not called.

If is it, try to do this: If "t" it's created on .m file, you must track it with tag

```
t.tag = 1001;

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if(textField.tag == 1001) {
        err.hidden=YES;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
try to set all property and change the name of the text field (some time works):

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,20,20)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
textField.placeholder = @"enter text";
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
textField.delegate = self;
[self.scroll addSubview:textField];
```

do you have try to put the textfield on the view? `[self.view addSubview:textField];` Do it works?

Comment: while giving delegate that is t.delegate=self;  i can call didbeginediting but cant type the changes keyboard at that time is not working except backspace

Comment: sorry, i  don't understand "but cant type the changes keyboard", do you want intercept text change?

Answer (score 0):

```
UITextField *t=[[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,20,20)]autorelease];
t.delegale=self;
[scroll addSubview:t];

if(a isEqualtoString:@"1")
{
   t.text=s;
}
if(a isEqualtoString:@"2")
{
   t.text=p;
}
if(a isEqualtoString:@"3")
{
   t.text=r;
}
```

//delegates of textfield

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
   if ([textField canResignFirstResponder])
   {
       [textField resignFirstResponder];
   }
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // add your method here
    return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
}
```

Comment: only one condition will be checked at once

Comment: it is working fine all delegate methods get called but only backspace in keyboard is working no other alphabets got worked

Comment: UITextfielddelegate in .h and t.delegate=self